# Sync Framework: conflicts not being handled in SimpleSyncProvider

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, syncfx

I have implemented a `FullEnumerationSimpleSyncProvider` that doesn't seem to be handling conflicts.

In the constructor I have set the following properties:

```
this.Configuration.CollisionConflictResolutionPolicy = CollisionConflictResolutionPolicy.ApplicationDefined;
this.Configuration.ConflictResolutionPolicy = ConflictResolutionPolicy.ApplicationDefined;

this.ItemConstraint += new EventHandler<SimpleSyncItemConstraintEventArgs>(OnItemConstraint);
this.ItemConflicting += new EventHandler<SimpleSyncItemConflictingEventArgs>(OnItemConflicting);
```

My event handlers for constraints and conflicts:

```
void OnItemConstraint(object sender, SimpleSyncItemConstraintEventArgs e)
{
    e.SetResolutionAction(ConstraintConflictResolutionAction.Merge);
}

void OnItemConflicting(object sender, SimpleSyncItemConflictingEventArgs e)
{
    e.SetResolutionAction(ConflictResolutionAction.Merge);
}
```

However, when I report a conflict in InsertItem() the constraint/conflict event handlers are never invoked.

```
public override void InsertItem(
        object itemData, 
        IEnumerable<SyncId> changeUnitsToCreate, 
        RecoverableErrorReportingContext recoverableErrorReportingContext, 
        out ItemFieldDictionary keyAndUpdatedVersion, 
        out bool commitKnowledgeAfterThisItem) {

            // ...snip...

            // Check if it is already there --- name collision
            if (itemAlreadyExists)
            {
                recoverableErrorReportingContext.RecordConstraintError(ConstructDictionary(item.ID));
                keyAndUpdatedVersion = null;
                commitKnowledgeAfterThisItem = false;

                return;
            }

            // ...snip...
}
```

I figured when calling `RecordConstraintError` the sync framework would invoke the appropriate event handler after `InsertItem` exited.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I'm fighting with the same problem for days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling concurrency conflict and set SetResolutionAction to ConflictResolutionAction.Merge, then your provider need to implement ISimpleSyncProviderConcurrencyConflictResolver Interface (ResolveUpdateUpdateConflict, ResolveLocalDeleteRemoteUpdateConflict, and ResolveLocalUpdateRemoteDeleteConflict.)

If you are handling constraint conflict and set ConstraintConflictResolutionAction to either Merge, RenameDestination or RenameSource, then your provider need to implement ISimpleSyncProviderConstraintConflictResolver interface.

[Microsoft Sync Framework Simple Provider – Concurrency Conflict Handling](http://zhongchenzhou.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/microsoft-sync-framework-simple-provider-conflict-handling/)

Comment: The problem is not about implementing interfaces. The problem is that the delegate is never raised when using neither recoverableErrorReportingContext.RecordConstraintError nor recoverableErrorReportingContext.RecordRecoverableErrorForChange. How are we supposed to resolve sync problem if those problems are never rised ?